# How to estimate schwartz space functions?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, schwartz-space

I'm currently learning about Schwartz spaces and I'm having difficulties when I'm trying to estimate the derivatives of the functions. For example when you have a function $e^{-ln(1+x^2)^N}$ and you want to verify whether it belongs to the Schwartz space or not. It's easy to compute 1st derivative(after that things go messy) and with that guess the general form which is a rational function $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$ where $Q(x)$ doesn't have any singularities. Now we have that $(1+x^2)^N\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}e^{-ln(1+x^2)^N}$. How to proceed here?

Comment: After evaluating a few more successive derivatives it appears the general form  of the $n^{th}$ order derivative is something like $$\frac{\partial^n\, e^{-\log ^N\left(x^2+1\right)}}{\partial x^n}=\frac{e^{-\log ^N\left(x^2+1\right)} \log ^{N-n}\left(x^2+1\right)}{\left(x^2+1\right)^n}\, f_n(x)\,,\quad n>0$$ where for example $$f_1(x)=-2 N x$$ and $$f_2(x)=2 N \left(-2 (N-1) x^2+2 N x^2 \log^N\left(x^2+1\right)+\left(x^2-1\right) \log\left(x^2+1\right)\right)$$ corresponding to the first and second order derivatives.

Comment: how do you deal with a situation when computing few more derivatives becomes very hard?

Comment: What are your assumptions on $N$? Assuming $N$ is a positive integer, the function $f_n(x)$ in the $n^{th}$ order derivative becomes increasingly more complex as $N$ increases as well as when $n$ increases, so coming up with a general expression for $f_n(x)$ seems very difficult. But if $e^{-ln(1+x^2)}$ can be shown to be a Schwartz function, does this not imply $e^{-ln(1+x^2)^N}$ is a Schwartz function for all $N\ge 1$?

Comment: This [WolframAlpha evaluation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Plot3D%5B%7BExp%5B-Log%5B1+%2B+x%5E2%5D%5EN%5D%7D%2C+%7Bx%2C+-10%2C+10%7D%2C+%7BN%2C+-5%2C+5%7D%5D) seems to suggest the Fourier transform of $e^{-ln(1+x^2)^N}$ perhaps converges for all $N\ge 1$.